# numbers in a alphanumeric string formating

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following javascript to format  the numbers in a string.

```
<?php if(count($businessesArray) > 0) { foreach($businessesArray as $business) { ?>
<div id="number2"><?php echo $business["name"]; ?></div></p> 

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#number2').html(($('#number2').html()).replace(/[0-9]/gi, '<big>$&</big>')) ;

</script>
<?php } } else { ?>
There is not any business added yet.
<?php } ?>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wLd5E/5/

but if apply to a value in a loop it format the first record only.

Where am I wrong?

Regards:

Comment: You are not showing the code that *actually* fails your expectations. That's definitely wrong.

Comment: Can you post this loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html elements have to have a unique ID. here you use id="number2" for all the DIV elements, this way your javascript always formats the first one.

try using unique ID in the foreach to give the DIV and the JQuery selector.

you can also just use a class on these DIV elements, and then you can format the content with one line of javascript using a JQuery selector for that class, it will do the trick for all elements of that class.

Comment: why not? for example you can set up a PHP variable before the loop to a starting number and then increment that in the foreach loop.

and then use that variable in the loop like this

    $i = 0;
    foreach (...)
    {
       $i++;
       ?>
       <div id="number<?php echo $i ?>">....
    }

Comment: using class, the format is applied to all columns, but the data is wrong. the first record value (repeating) is displayed in the column.

Comment: the $i will be some incrementing number, I don't want to display that.

Comment: if you wanna do it using a class the JavaScript line should look like this:

      $('.myClass').each(function()
      {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/0-9]/gi, '<big>$&</big>'));
      });